# Why tracking pixel is using a picture?

Tags: php, google-analytics, visitors

I need to create a tracking pixel for my website and based on my researches it uses a 1 * 1 pixel image, I am wondering why it is using images? is there any other alternative?

Comment: You can use anything that has to be requested from the server, but you don't want something that is visible in the rendered markup, so a minimum-size transparent pixel is the most appropriate element to request. Why would you want any alternative?

Comment: My guess would be that they wish to cut down on HTTP requests. Unfortunately, this cannot be done due to the fact that it only works by tracking requests.

Comment: One of the problems is privacy, google owns the data.